# jQuery: delay event call in widget

Tags: jquery, event-handling, delay

I can't find out how to delay an event handler for a widget.
I bind the event like this:

```
enable: function () {
    this.options.isEnabled = true;
    this.element.bind("keyup", $.proxy(this, "_populateList"));
},
```

I want to call "_populateList" with a delay. but my attempts with setTimeout are not working.

The "_populateList":

```
_populateList: function (event) {
    var that = this;
    // do my stuffs
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Where's your setTimeout use attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
enable: function () {
    this.options.isEnabled = true;
    var that = this;
    this.element.bind("keyup", function(event){
       $(this)
          .delay(1000) // delayed time in milliseconds
          .queue(function(next){
             that._populateList(event);
             next();
          });
    });
},
```

Comment: if I set 1000 in delay, nothing happens after 1 second

Comment: @user706058: Updated the code in my answer. Try again, please. :)

Comment: @Shef same, nothing happens but an error occurs: "_populateList is not defined"

Comment: @user706058: Try to reference `_populateList(event);` with the name of the object holder in front, like `objectHolder._populateList(event);`

Comment: @Shef: I tried with: this. which is the widget object reference: this._populateList(event) but that errors with "_populateList is not a function", although I see it being listed debbuging with FireBug

Comment: @Shef: "_populateList is not defined" error with your updated code and "this._populateList is not a function" when using `this._populateList(event);` instead of `._populateList(event);`

Comment: @user706058: If the updated code doesn't work, please move `var that = this;` above the `keyup` binding.